# How to create a subwindow using SDL

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

How to create a new window in SDL that is inserted into the main window? So it could be focused, have separate drawing context and process events separately.

Answer (score 8):

### Window within a window

You can create a window within a window using the example below. The example will spawn two windows, where `subWindow` is inside `mainWindow.` The sub window can be moved out of the main window. If you want the sub window to be "stuck" inside the main window, you could use the [`SDL_WindowEvent`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowEvent?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryStruct%5Cb%29%7C%28SDLStructTemplate%29) to see when the window was moved and then force it back into place using [`SDL_SetWindowPosition()`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetWindowPosition?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryAPI%5Cb%29%7C%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29)

### Separate event processing

You can't do this in `SDL2` as far as I know. But [some](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_KeyboardEvent), if not all, event type has the `windowID` member variable. Use this along with [`SDL_GetWindowID()`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowID?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryAPI%5Cb%29%7C%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29) on your `SDL_Window`s to find which window had the focus at the time of the event.

### Example code

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

    // Set postion and size for main window
    int mainSizeX = 600;
    int mainSizeY = 600;
    int mainPosX = 100;
    int mainPosY = 100;

    // Set postion and size for sub window based on those of main window
    int subSizeX = mainSizeX / 2;
    int subSizeY = mainSizeY / 2;
    int subPosX = mainPosX + mainSizeX / 4;
    int subPosY = mainPosY + mainSizeY / 4;

    // Set up main window
    SDL_Window* mainWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( "Main Window", mainPosX, mainPosY, mainSizeX, mainSizeY, 0 );
    SDL_Renderer* mainRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer( mainWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED );
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( mainRenderer , 255, 0, 0, 255 );

    // Set up sub window
    SDL_Window* subWindow  = SDL_CreateWindow( "Sub Window" , subPosX, subPosY, subSizeX, subSizeY, 0 );
    SDL_Renderer* subRenderer  = SDL_CreateRenderer( subWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED );
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( subRenderer , 0, 255, 0, 255 );

    // Render empty ( red ) background in mainWindow
    SDL_RenderClear( mainRenderer );
    SDL_RenderPresent( mainRenderer );

    // Render empty ( green ) background in subWindow
    SDL_RenderClear( subRenderer );
    SDL_RenderPresent( subRenderer );

    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

This example will render a green window with half the width and height in the middle of a red window.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is wondering how to render child window always on top of parent window and avoid problem with input focus on parent window:

1. set `SDL_HINT_MOUSE_FOCUS_CLICKTHROUGH` to `"1"`.
2. use `SDL_RiseWindow` on each child when parent window receives `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_FOCUS_GAINED`

Comment: Just for everyone else: Setting the hint is done using `SDL_SetHint`

Comment: Beware that systems don’t have to honor that hint. I’m using Mint Cinnamon, and it seems to be completely ignored. :-/

Answer (score 2):

[SDL_CreateWindowFrom](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindowFrom?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryAPI%5Cb%29%7C%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29) along with [SDL_SetWindowInputFocus](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetWindowInputFocus?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryAPI%5Cb%29%7C%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29) might be what you are looking for.